# How to create single pipeline(s) for all projects in an organization

Tags: azure-devops, devops

I have more than 35 projects in an organization in Azure DevOps. These are the solutions of a Single product. Right now I am creating build and release pipelines for each project one by one.

If I create a pipeline for a single project and release the build, I want devops to create pipeline & releases builds for all the other projects(in the same organization) together at once.

For eg, There are projects A,B,C & D. If I create a release pipeline for Project A, will Devops automatically Release build for other projects "B,C & D" in the same organization at the same time.

We need to avoid creating pipelines for each projects one by one. Is this possible and is there any scripting or configuration to achieve this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: just dont do that. its will be a mess you cant support at all

Answer (score 1):

The process of setting up multiple release definitions with the exact same tasks can be very time consuming and difficult to manage -- fortunately, our team solved this problem using Task Groups!

Task Groups allow you to bundle multiple steps into a single "group", parameterize them, and then invoke them like a single step. You can also edit the Task Group at any time which will cascade to all places where it's used.

The other consideration is that you can bundle your custom variables into Variable Groups and reuse them between Release Definitions. Having your configuration reusable also has the benefit of only having to edit a single item.

I'd recommend:

1. Create a single release definition as a golden reference example.
2. Add your build steps for a single stage/environment
3. Once you're happy with this release definition, multi-select the steps you want to bundle into a group, open the context menu and select the option to convert to a Task Group. This will remove the steps from your release and move them to the Task Group.
4. Customize the Task Group with the appropriate parameters and then save it.
5. Modify your release definition to use the Task group parameters.
6. Add the additional stages to your environment, and add your custom Task Group to each parameterizing with configuration specific to the environment.
7. Once you're happy with the Release Definition -- use the Clone feature to create 34 more instances.

The same approach can be applied to builds.

Comment: Hi bryanbcook, Thanks for the response. 

The 35 projects I mentioned are not the same. Some of them are Remote event receivers, web jobs , console applications etc. I want to release builds for all these projects at a same time, not one by one by going into the projects and creating builds for each one of them. 

To be short - I have multiple projects in different types like web jobs , console applications etc. I want to create build and release pipelines for all of them at a single click. Is there any config or scripts for that?

Comment: @poovarasan No! if you have multiple types of builds, how do you except the "click" will know which build type the project need?

Comment: Azure DevOps does a great job at separating "building something" from "deploying something". In the case of a "single click" to build AND release something you'd be mixing concerns a bit. There isn't anything natively within Azure DevOps that would allow you to orchestrate multiple releases simultaneously, but you could create a single "big bang" release where you attach the build artifacts from multiple builds into a single release and automate them in the order you specify. Failing this, a powershell script to create/trigger releases against the REST API is also feasible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Bryan. 
I am new to Azure devops. Can you please elaborate about this -

Comment: I'd start by reading the details on what a release definition is.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/?view=azure-devops Having a big bang release is effectively a single release pipeline that uses multiple artifacts. In your case 35 artifacts, which is ridiculous -- don't create a monolithic release pipeline. Your better option is following the steps I've outlined above and using the API to trigger 35 separate releases.

Comment: If you're interested in using the REST API, I ask you to consider that you ask a separate question on how to automate triggering multiple releases using the API.